# storing extracted characters in a vector of strings

Tags: c++, stdvector

I should reasonably be able to store `char`s in a `std::vector` of strings, if the conversion is considered.

Here is the try:

```
vector<string> f (vector<string> input)
{
    vector<string> output;
    for (int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)                 // vector iteration
    {
        for (int j=0;j<input[i].size(); j++)           // string iteration
        {
            output.push_back(string(input[i].at(j)));  // access to characters
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

`input[i]` is a `string`, and `input[i].at(j)` is a `char`; thus, I've converted it to `string` before pushing to `vector<string>`.

I'm wondering what's wrong with this approach. Especially, the compiler's error is undecipherable to me:

```
invalid conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type {aka char}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

**Edit:**

`f` must work as follows.

Suppose there are 3 strings in the `input` vector: `{abcd,efdr,loab}`; then, the `output` shall extract all atormic characters like: `{abcdefdrloab}`

Comment: use iterator for coping

Comment: @HariomSingh: Could you explicitly explain the point a little bit?

Comment: You can see the reason from the error message: They can not convert from `char` to `const char*`. `char` is your input[i].at(j), and by checking string's constructor, it doesn't accept `char`, but, it does accept an address pointed by `char*` and a number indicate how many `char` will be fetched from that address.

Comment: {abcd,efdr,loab} is it {"abcd,efdr,loab"} or {"abcd","efdr","oab"}

Comment: @HariomSingh: "loab".

Comment: got the working solution

Comment: Do you want a vector with one string in it, or a vector with a number of strings of length one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct your error change

```
    output.push_back(string(&input[i].at(j)));
```

from

```
  output.push_back(string(input[i].at(j)));
```

Basically

```
**for (int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)  \\vector iteration**
```

This is a wrong way of iteration .For containers iterators should be used for iterating

Below copies string from one vector (Use of iterator and stl you can use copy_if or lambda)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;
vector<string> f (vector<string> input)
{
    vector<string> output;
    copy(input.begin(),input.end(),back_inserter(output));

    return output;
}

int main()

{
    vector<string> h{"hello"},x;
    x=f(h);
    copy(x.begin(),x.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));
}
```

Output

```
hello Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But to answer you question and fix of your Code

Below is the modified code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<string> f (vector<string> input)
{
    vector<string> output;
    for (int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<input[i].size(); j++)
        {
            output.push_back(string(&input[i].at(j)));
        }
    }

    return output;
}
vector<string> fi (vector<string> input)
{
    vector<string> output;
    copy(input.begin(),input.end(),back_inserter(output));

    return output;
}

int main()

{
    vector<string> h{"hello"},x,y;
    x=fi(h);
    y=f(h);
    copy(x.begin(),x.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));
    copy(y.begin(),y.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));

}
```

Output

```
hello hello ello llo lo o Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Solution after the edit**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void push_back_vec(std::vector<T>& v, Args&&... args)
{
    (v.push_back(args), ...);
}


int main()

{
    vector<string>x;
    push_back_vec(x, "abc", "cds", "ma");

    string a = accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), string(""));
    cout<<a;
}
```

Output

```
abccdsmaProgram ended with exit code: 0
```

More easier format

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    vector<string>x{"abc", "cds", "ma"},a;
    a.push_back(accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), string("")));
    copy(a.begin(),a.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));

}
```

Comment: The improved `f` seemingly does not follow the expected logic, e.g., `input = {abc,cds,ma}` must lead to {abccdsma}, but the `output` is different.

Comment: Can you add this to your query , so that I can add the solution

Comment: added your  set of Input and expected output so that it will help others

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: "For containers iterators should be used for iterating". That's a C++98 approach. Since C++11 we use `for (auto element: container) { }`

Comment: @MSalters only when you need to explicitly loop. I would rewrite the body of `fi` as `return { input.begin(), input.end() };`

Comment: @HariomSingh Can we do something like in memory than copying it to another array.

Answer (score 0):

try this `string(1, input[i].at(j))`